# Multicolumn legend with different xdata in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

I would like to use legendcolumn.m for a subplot that includes different xdata as below:

1. scatter(m,n)
2. scatter(m,t)
3. plot(f,h)
4. plot(f,j)
5. plot(f,k).

my code was

```
"legend_str = ['Individual 1-h averaged SODAR data ';...
              'Bin-averaged SODAR data            ';...
              'Fit to Bin-averaged SODAR data     ';...
              'Quan and Hu (2009)                 ';...
              'Al-Jiboori et al.(2002)            ';...
              'Xu et al.(1997)                    ';...
              'Panofsky et al. (1977)             ']; 
 [legend_h,object_h,plot_h,text_strings]=  columnlegend(2, legend_str);"
```

in run this error has been appeared:
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

```
Error in ==> columnlegend at 61
xdata = get(object_h(numlines+1), 'xdata');

Error in ==> Su_Sv_Sw_self_bin_average_nafiseh_constant_adapted_general at 201
 [legend_h,object_h,plot_h,text_strings]=  columnlegend(2, legend_str);
```

I would appreciate if any one help me.
thanks

Comment: maybe because you have 5 plots and the legend you're using has 7 entries?

Answer (score 1):

In your question is not clear the `type` of `plot` you wnat to generate, that is: a set of 5 `subplot` or 1 `plot` with 5 entries.

In the first case, the function `columnlegend` can not be used.

Looking at the code of the function you can see that it first generate a "standard" MatLab `legend`:

```
[legend_h,object_h,plot_h,text_strings] = legend(str);
```

then it uses the returned `handles` to modify the components of the `legend` in order to distribute them on several colums.

This implies that a mismatch occurs between the number of entities plotted in the `subplot` and the number of items in the legend sting.

I the second case, 1 axes with 5 entities, the function `columnlegend` can be used, nevertheless, you have to define the legend string as `cellarray`:

```
legend_str = {'Individual 1-h averaged SODAR data', ...
   'Bin-averaged SODAR data',...
   'Fit to Bin-averaged SODAR data',...
   'Quan and Hu (2009)',...
   'Al-Jiboori et al.(2002)',...
   'Xu et al.(1997)',...
   'Panofsky et al. (1977)'};
```

Of course, you have first to fix the error identified by @Benoit_11.

Actually, the error you've got has its origin in the line

```
numlines = length(str);
```

having defined `legend_str` as an `array` of `char` its size is (7x35) and `length` (unfortunately for you) returns  `max(size(X))`, that means, in your case, `35`.

This value is then used as `numlines`, but your legend string has only 7 lines.

Also (but this is simply a suggestion), it would be better try to reduce the length of legend's strings, otherwise they will span across all the axes (the legend `location` options of the function `columnlegend` do not include putting the legend outside the axes).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to divide my legend to three parts, and plot each of them by a subplot, because I had 3 subplots that each of them has 5 entries.